# Multi-indexed Dataframe Join (Keep updated data if not NaN and Append on new Indices)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two DataFrames with multiple indices named `df_base` and `df_updates`. I want to combine these DataFrames into a single DataFrame and keep the multi indices.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_base = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "price": {
...             ("2019-01-01", "1001"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-01", "1002"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-01", "1003"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-02", "1001"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-02", "1002"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-02", "1003"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-03", "1001"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-03", "1002"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-03", "1003"): 100,
...         }
...     },
... )
>>> df_base.index.names = ["date", "id"]
>>> df_base.convert_dtypes()
                 price
date       id         
2019-01-01 1001    100
           1002    100
           1003    100
2019-01-02 1001    100
           1002    100
           1003    100
2019-01-03 1001    100
           1002    100
           1003    100
>>>
>>> df_updates = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "price": {
...             ("2019-01-01", "1001"): np.nan,
...             ("2019-01-01", "1002"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-01", "1003"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-02", "1001"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-02", "1002"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-02", "1003"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-03", "1001"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-03", "1002"): 100,
...             ("2019-01-03", "1003"): 100,
...         }
...     }
... )
>>> df_updates.index.names = ["date", "id"]
>>> df_updates.convert_dtypes()
                 price
date       id         
2019-01-01 1001   <NA>
           1002     99
           1003     99
           1004    100
```

I want to combine them with the following rules:

1. Keep the old data if the new data is not specified (NaN)
2. Append the new data if the indices doesn't exist in the base DataFrame

I already tried using `.join` but it raise an error

```py
>>> df_base.join(df_updates)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 21
     ...

ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['price'], dtype='object')
```

even if I added suffix, it just make the data more complex (need another solution)

I also already tried using `.update`, but the new data with different indices from base were not included in the results

```py
>>> df_base.update(df_updates)
>>> df_base
                 price
date       id         
2019-01-01 1001  100.0
           1002   99.0
           1003   99.0
2019-01-02 1001  100.0
           1002  100.0
           1003  100.0
2019-01-03 1001  100.0
           1002  100.0
           1003  100.0
```

And the last, I also try a "tricky" operation

```py
>>> df_base.update(df_updates)
>>> df_base = df_updates.combine_first(df_base)
>>> df_base
                 price
date       id         
2019-01-01 1001  100.0
           1002   99.0
           1003   99.0
           1004  100.0
2019-01-02 1001  100.0
           1002  100.0
           1003  100.0
2019-01-03 1001  100.0
           1002  100.0
           1003  100.0
```

It is the result that I expected, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution for this case, I try using `%timeit`, and the results are

```py
>>> %timeit df_base.update(df_updates)
345 µs ± 17.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit df_updates.combine_first(df_base)
1.36 ms ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

when using large data the results are

```py
>>> %timeit df_base.update(df_updates)
2.38 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit df_updates.combine_first(df_base)
9.65 ms ± 400 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Is that the best solution for my case or is there any more efficient/optimized function (I expected a single liner pandas function)? Thanks!

#### Edit 1: Full Code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_base = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "price": {
            ("2019-01-01", "1001"): 100,
            ("2019-01-01", "1002"): 100,
            ("2019-01-01", "1003"): 100,
            ("2019-01-02", "1001"): 100,
            ("2019-01-02", "1002"): 100,
            ("2019-01-02", "1003"): 100,
            ("2019-01-03", "1001"): 100,
            ("2019-01-03", "1002"): 100,
            ("2019-01-03", "1003"): 100,
        }
    },
)
df_base.index.names = ["date", "id"]
df_base.convert_dtypes()


df_updates = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "price": {
            ("2019-01-01", "1001"): np.nan,
            ("2019-01-01", "1002"): 100,
            ("2019-01-01", "1003"): 100,
            ("2019-01-02", "1001"): 100,
            ("2019-01-02", "1002"): 100,
            ("2019-01-02", "1003"): 100,
            ("2019-01-03", "1001"): 100,
            ("2019-01-03", "1002"): 100,
            ("2019-01-03", "1003"): 100,
        }
    }
)
df_updates.index.names = ["date", "id"]
df_updates.convert_dtypes()

df_base.update(df_updates)
df_base = df_updates.combine_first(df_base)
df_base
```

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame constructors of the inputs?

Comment: Yup, already added the constructor @mozway

Comment: Without the `...` would be great ;)

Comment: I just wanted to make it prettier :D added the complete code at the bottom

Comment: But not easy to use to reproduce the data ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `update` then `combine_first`, just `combine_first`:

```
df_base = df_updates.combine_first(df_base)
```

Output:

```
                 price
date       id         
2019-01-01 1001  100.0
           1002   99.0
           1003   99.0
           1004  100.0
2019-01-02 1001  100.0
           1002  100.0
           1003  100.0
2019-01-03 1001  100.0
           1002  100.0
           1003  100.0
```

Comment: the value for date `2019-01-01` and id `1001` should be 100 instead of NaN as I described in 1st Rule which can be achieved by using `update`

Comment: @bambangkode then a simple `combine_first`!

Comment: you are right! my bad just only focused on `update` big thanks @mozway!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
df_updates = df_updates[df_updates["price"].notna()]

df_base = df_base.reindex(df_base.index.union(df_updates.index))
df_base.loc[df_updates.index, "price"] = df_updates["price"]
```

According to my "benchmark" it should be twice as fast as your solution with `update/combine_first`, but it depends on your data.

Comment: on my actual data, it's not only "price" but also other columns (dynamic). and I think it wouldn't work on your first line, since it has multiple columns. but thanks anyway, I already found the answer from @mozway